# Difficulty understanding particular lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This is a really simple question, I would imagine, for someone who knows lambda well. I am just now learning it and have run across one expression that doesn't make sense to me.

From what I understand, lambda expressions pass in the variable specified on the left side and runs the code on the right. For instance

```
myFunction = x => x + x;
```

so myFunction(2) would return 4.

Anyhow, I was looking at a linq query on here and saw this:

```
IEnumerable<int> numQuery2 = numbers.Where(num => num % 2 == 0).OrderBy(n => n);
```

The `n => n` ... what does that do? Why not just say `OrderBy(n)`? All you are doing it passing n into a function that just returns `n`. >_> What's happening here?

Comment: Suppose you have a function `int F(int x) { return x; }`, then you could use `.OrderBy(F)`

Comment: In more lay language:  you have to tell OrderBy which key or property you want to use to sort.  MSDN example:  `IEnumerable<Pet> query = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Age);`.  Saying OrderBy(Pet) wouldn't be helpful since OrderBy doesn't know how to arrange a Pet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break this down:

```
numbers
```

This is a collection of `integers`.

```
.Where(num => num % 2 == 0)
```

This is saying "find me all items in my collection where my number modulus 2 = 0".

```
.OrderBy(n => n);
```

This is then ordering the list. Because the list is of integers, and the specified item is an integer, it will be ordered numerically, lowest to highest.

The reason you need `n => n` is because you could sort by something other than the value. Say, for example, the length of the item as a string

```
.OrderBy(n => n.ToString().Length)
```

Obviously, for integers, this serves no purpose. But for other data types, like classes, this is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Yours and Jon Skeet's were both extremely informative and fit my needs perfectly, but you got first post so you get the answer!

Comment: @user1548103: Actually my post was about a minute earlier, but I wouldn't recommend using time as the way of determining which answer to accept anyway. It should be the most *helpful* answer, in whatever way you choose to decide that. (I'm not suggesting you switch accepted answers - I'm just suggesting that time isn't the best metric to use.)

Answer (score 9):

> The `n => n` ... what does that do?

It just maps any value to itself. It's an identity function.

> Why not just say OrderBy(n)?

Because `n` isn't a variable in scope - it wouldn't be valid to call it like that. That's not a lambda expression, so it would just try to use `n` as a normal method argument.

Your code *is* just trying to say "order this sequence by the whole of each element" rather than projecting each element to some other value, but there's no way of saying that directly.

`OrderBy` *requires* a projection from the element type to the ordering key type - it's just that in this case we want the identity projection.

You could write your own extra extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderNaturally<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source.OrderBy(item => item);
}
```

And then change your original statement to:

```
IEnumerable<int> numQuery2 = numbers.Where(num => num % 2 == 0).OrderNaturally();
```

if you found that more readable.

Alternatively, you could create a `Functions` class with some useful static readonly fields:

```
public static class Functions<T>
{
    public static readonly Func<T, T> Identity = x => x;
    public static readonly Func<T, T> DefaultValue => x => default(T);
    public static readonly Func<T, string> ToString = x => x == null ? null : x.ToString();
    ...
}
```

Then:

```
IEnumerable<int> numQuery2 = numbers.Where(num => num % 2 == 0)
                                    .OrderBy(Functions<int>.Identity)
```

I don't think I *would* do that... I'm just suggesting things to think about :)

Comment: If you change it `Order`, then you can actually have it use fewer characters to declare throughout your code, while still having decent readability. However, if you wanted to have a similar extension method for `ThenBy`, a `Then` method is, to me, not readable, while a `ThenNaturally` would be perfectly readable.

Comment: @TimS.: No, I wouldn't call it just `Order` - that doesn't explain it clearly enough in my view.

Answer (score 0):

`n => n` means that the function accepts one argument as it's input and returns it's input as the return value.

> Why not just say `OrderBy(n)`

How would you know that `n` is a lambda?  What indication is there that it's a function?  If you had a function, named `n`, that accepted an integer and returned that same integer, then you *could* do that, but my guess is that isn't what you were thinking of.

I know you didn't ask it but:

> Is there some alternate syntax that the C# compiler team could have used to cover the special case of the "identity lambda"?

(An "identity lambda" is the technical term for a function that only returns it's one input value).

Yes.  They could have.  They didn't, probably because they just didn't consider it worth the time/effort, given that writing an identity function is easy enough without any special syntax.